# redirect: "manual" in fetch redirects to the request URL instead of redirecting to header location in response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, http-redirect, http-status-code-302

I have the below code which am using to get the response header location.

```
 let callAuthorize = async() => {
        try {
        const authorizeResponse = await fetch(requesturl,
{redirect: "manual", mode:'cors',
        headers: {
          "Cache-Control": "no-store",
          "Accept-Charset": "UTF-8",
          "Access-Control-Expose-Headers": "location"
        }
      });
      if (authorizeResponse.type === "opaqueredirect") {
          window.location.href = authorizeResponse.url;
      }
      }
      catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
```

but it redirects to the requesturl instead of redirecting to header location in response.

with normal fetch call am unable to grab the response header, because of CORS issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read the redirect location directly.  As a workaround, you can navigate the browser to the `opaqueredirect` response, if you store it in a cache and use a service worker to replay the response.  See an example below with one same-origin redirect followed by two cross-origin redirects.

`index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head><title>Navigate to opaqueredirect</title></head>
  <body>
    <button id=button disabled>Navigate to opaqueredirect</button>
  </body>
  <script>
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js');
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
        button.disabled = false;
        button.onclick = () => {
            fetch('/redirect1', { redirect: 'manual' }).then(
                (response) => {
                    if (response.type === 'opaqueredirect') {
                        const urlToCache = new URL(response.url);
                        const uuid = crypto.randomUUID();
                        urlToCache.searchParams.set('cacheId', uuid);
                        const requestToCache = new Request(urlToCache);
                        caches.open('cacheId').then((cache) => {
                            cache.put(requestToCache, response).then(() => {
                                window.location.assign(urlToCache);
                            }).catch(console.error);
                        }).catch(console.error);
                    }
                },
            ).catch(console.error);
        };
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

`serve.json`:

```json
{
  "redirects": [
      {
          "source": "/redirect1",
          "destination": "/redirect2",
          "type": 302
      },
      {
          "source": "/redirect2",
          "destination": "https://mock.httpstatus.io/307",
          "type": 302
      }
  ]
}
```

`sw.js`:

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  if (new URL(event.request.url).searchParams.get('cacheId')) {
    event.respondWith(caches.open('cacheId').then(async (cache) => {
      const cacheMatch = await cache.match(event.request);
      if (cacheMatch) {
        cache.delete(event.request).then(() => { }).catch(console.error);
        return cacheMatch;
      }
      return fetch(event.request);
    }));
  }
});
```

Run `npx -y serve` in a directory containing the above files, then open `localhost:3000` in your browser.  Then click the button and the redirect will be followed to `https://mock.httpstatus.io/200`.